# Xamarin Forms Release apk Installed with disabled Open Button and disappears

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, release

Since last month when I started a new Xamarin forms project(android only) I always debug it successfully. but after release archive i could not install apk in mobile phone successfully, I was using Visual Studio Community 20017.

I tried lot of solutions after that I updated everything and install Visual Studio Community 2019, and created a new tabbed project and did nothing. I just run it again on debug mode on a Samsung galaxy j7 next(Android 8.1, API 27) Target Framework Android 9 API 29. new app runs successfully with tabbed pages.

Then I change the mode to release and no property changes. Then I achieve it an signed and generated APK.

Then I Copy this APK to Mobile and try to install it. it installed successfully but with Done button enable and Open button disabled. I clicked on Done button. then I looked for app in launched it was not even list of apps.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What did you do for the release archive? Please check the link below about the details to Archive for Publishing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#archive-for-publishing

Comment: Thank you wendy zang, ! But I got the solution it was android sdk updated to 29 as i downgrade it....everything was fine...i dont know why ? Even i tried in VS Community2019 ..Apk worked only when i compiled it with sdk 25